# Insert into table if time to be inserted is within time range

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sql-insert, mariadb-10.1

Is there a way to insert data into a table if time is currently within the default time range?

I have a table time_tb and has columns

```
id, time_start, time_end, time_inserted, status
```

time_start and time_end having default values,
time_start='08:00:00' and time_end='08:59:00'

If time_inserted = '08:10:00' then data would be inserted and status column will be marked "present", if it time_inserted = '09:00:00' then status column will be "late".

Comment: Status appears to be redundant

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression to check the value of `time_inserted` and compute the `status` accordingly. Possibly something like:

```
insert into time_tb(time_start, time_end, time_inserted, status)
select
    '08:00:00',
    '08:59:00,
    @time_inserted,
    case 
        when @time_inserted >= '09:00:00' then 'late'
        when @time_inserted >= '08:00:00' then 'present'
        else 'put something relevant here'
    end
```

Another option is to use a computed column (so you don't need to put the logic in each and every `INSSERT` statement).

```
alter table time_tb modify status varchar(20) as (
    case 
        when time_inserted >= '09:00:00' then 'late'
        when time_inserted >= '08:00:00' then 'present'
        else 'put something relevant here'
    end
);
```

You might also make the computation dynamic:

```
case 
    when time_inserted >= time_end then 'late'
    when time_inserted >= time_start then 'present'
    else 'put something relevant here'
end
```

As final thought, following up on the comment by Strawberry: another option would be not to store this derived information, which can very well be computed on the fly when querying the table:

```
select
    t.*,
    case 
        when time_inserted >= time_end then 'late'
        when time_inserted >= time_start then 'present'
        else 'put something relevant here'
    end status
from mytable t
```

Comment: But then why store derived data at all?

Comment: @Strawberry: yes that's a good point, I updated my answer accordingly.